# How to install Tea Commerce Starter Kit on Umbraco 7.1.6 version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7, umbraco-teacommerce

We have an existing Umbraco 7.1.6 website. We have decided to use the TeaCommerce on our site. I installed the Tea Commerce Package and now can see the new section called Tea Commerce where you have access to stores. However, I am not sure yet how to create the production catalog as the umbraco content node and use the Tea Commerce section. When I installed the package, it gave me few lines of javascript reference that I need to add on the layout page. But I am not sure how to get the StoreId value.

It would had been much easier if I could install the starter kit easily to the existing website.

Any ideas or directions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you posted this on Umbraco forum? http://our.umbraco.org/forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use package repository or install starter kit menu item.
http://screencast.com/t/QW3S5mgS